# Fluent nhibernate, delete a non-nullable property and replace it

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an object with a non-nullable property.

```
class Notebook {
  Blueprint Blueprint { get; set; }
}
```

### Mapping

```
// ...
NotebookMap() {
 // ...
 References(x => x.Blueprint)
  .Not.Nullable()
  .Cascade.All();
}
```

Okay, great. Wonderful.

What happens if I want to change the `Blueprint` attached to a notebook, and delete the old blueprint? This doesn't work..

```
notebook.Blueprint = // new blueprint code.;
```

That works fine... but then the old blueprint isn't deleted, it just hangs around in code happily and wastes space.

If I try this ..

```
session.Delete(notebook.Blueprint);
```

I get an error, because now the field is null (and it has to be non-nullable).

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var oldBlueprint = notebook.Blueprint;
notebook.Blueprint = // new blueprint code;
session.Flush(); // might or might not be needed
session.Delete(oldBlueprint);
```

Of course, the blueprint may be referenced by another notebook, so the delete may still fail.

Comment: This did not work, either. By the time the flush happened, the `oldBlueprint` was now null.

Comment: try `var oldBlueprint = Session.Get<Blueprint>(notebook.Blueprint);`